# JavaScript nodejs

Tags: javascript

Need sample nodejs application to understand how to send table content from client to server and server save the content to json file, when first time client html loads then server should read the json file and send it to client and client show the content in table in html

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on nodejs. Did you google it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to watch [TheNewBoston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-j7uqU7sI&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_) on Youtube. His english is clear and you will quickly understand nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need is to have a closer look at the following topics:

1) Nodejs **HTTP, HTTPS** modules which are responsible for creating your http/https listeners. 
2) Nodejs **FS module** - responsible for I/O operationsm which weill let you save incoming content as a file.

With this **2 modules** you will be able to acomplish your goals:  recieving sending and saving data on your server.

Also i would not recomend using frameworks untill you got familiar with core nodejs functionality.

also you will find an example of each module use on official nodejs website https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html